# New Mail notification does not come to the top

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, notifications

I am running Office 2010, on Windows 8.1.

In Outlook, I have two email accounts set up, **1)** my personal POP3 email **2)** my work Exchange email.

We recently moved our corporate email into Exchange, hosted on https://outlook.office365.com.
(We used to be using an old POP3 software hosted in our location).

Ever since we moved to Exchange for our corporate email, the little popup notification for new incoming mail does not work properly on either account. When new mail arrives, it still shows the little pop up that appears, waits a few seconds and then fades out. **BUT** - ever since the switch to Exchange for the corporate, the little notification popup always comes up at the bottom of the window stack, just above the desktop. It refuses to come to the top of the window stack, which means I never see it.

I've tried, per a thread on another site, creating a rule that said essentially:
`When new mail arrives, show the desktop alert`
but that did not help.

This *used to* work fine, up until we switched our corporate account to Exchange.
The problem affects both accounts in Outlook (work and personal).

Comment: I can't see how your change to an Exchange account type would affect the windows Z-order of your machine.  Has anyone else in the company been affected the same way on their computers?  Have you tested it while logged into your workstation as a different user?  Have you tried repairing and/or reinstalling Office/Outlook?

Comment: I wouldn't think it should affect it either, but it was as soon as I switched the corporate account from POP3 to Exchange that I noticed this happening. I haven't tried logging in as another user. We're a small company, and each use our own laptops, so there is no other user to use really. I haven't tried repairing Outlook, that is a good suggestion, I'll have to give that a go later, don't have my install media with me.